# Prevent Hacking Via Facebook Login API

Tags: ajax, angular, ionic-framework, facebook-login

I'm developing an app with **Ionic 3** and **Angular 4**, and also implementing **Login With Facebook** button (and logic).
I don't understand how to secure this process.
The API returns the user's email + id and then I need to send them to my server to register / log in the user.
But how can I be sure that nobody "fake" the ajax call with those user email & id? And skip the whole Facebook Button process?
I don't get it at all - no matter what the API returns - I need to send it to the server via AJAX, and anyone can fake this process and send specific parameters with AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way is to send the Access Token to the server and make the API call to the Facebook API there. You can/should activate "Require App Secret" in the App settings:

> Only allow calls from a server and require app secret or app secret
>   proof for all API calls.

Comment: if I under stand correctly - there is going to be 2 facebook calls: one from the App to FB, and then from my App to my server, and then from my server to FB again. Am I right?

Comment: yes, you would need 2 calls anyway, one for the login (or for getting the access token) - which can be client side, one for the email - server side.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is - backend!
You should always verify the token in the server side to prevent "hacks" like you said

Comment: wow this is a very old question but thanks anyway!